# analytics:reportChart and removing "As of..." subtitle

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-charting

How do I get rid of the reference "As of..." subtitle using the visualforce analytics:reportChart ?

[image]

```
<apex:page standardController="Audit__c"  showHeader="false" >
<apex:variable var="audit" value="{!Audit__c}" /> 

<style>
.asOfDate{display:none;}
</style>
......

   <apex:panelGrid columns="3" id="Grid1">
              <analytics:reportChart reportId="00O16000007LVFN" size="tiny" cacheResults="true" showRefreshButton="false" filter="[{column:'Audit__c.Name',operator:'equals',value:'{!Audit__c.Name}'}]"/>
              <analytics:reportChart reportId="00O16000007LVFJ" size="tiny" cacheResults="true" showRefreshButton="false" filter="[{column:'Audit__c.Name',operator:'equals',value:'{!Audit__c.Name}'}]"/>
              <analytics:reportChart reportId="00O16000007LVFE" size="tiny" cacheResults="true" showRefreshButton="false" filter="[{column:'Audit__c.Name',operator:'equals',value:'{!Audit__c.Name}'}]"/>
    </apex:panelGrid>
```

Comment: Added .asOfDate{display:none;} to visualforce page will take out the subtitle. Not documented.

Answer (score 2):

Updated the code with the addition of:

```
<style>
.asOfDate{display:none;}
</style>
```